# Multi-indexed row and columns

Tags: python, pivot-table, data-science, crosstab

How can I do multi index of rows and columns in python?

[image]

Comment: `df.loc[:, 'B']` Also, what do you mean by "How can I do"? Do what?  Given the image, I assume select all columns for `B`.

Answer (score 1):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index

```
import pandas as pd  # Pandas isn't mentioned in the tags, but the image looks like a pandas dataframe.

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[f'System {s}' for s in 'ABC'], list('FM')], names=[None, 'Sex'])
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 1), ('B', 2), ('B', 3), ('C', 1), ('C', 2)])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=1, columns=cols, index=idx)

>>> df
              A     B        C   
              1  2  1  2  3  1  2
         Sex                     
System A F    1  1  1  1  1  1  1
         M    1  1  1  1  1  1  1
System B F    1  1  1  1  1  1  1
         M    1  1  1  1  1  1  1
System C F    1  1  1  1  1  1  1
         M    1  1  1  1  1  1  1

>>> df.loc[:, 'B']
              1  2  3
         Sex         
System A F    1  1  1
         M    1  1  1
System B F    1  1  1
         M    1  1  1
System C F    1  1  1
         M    1  1  1
```

Or using IndexSlice.

```
>>> df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice['B', :]]
              B      
              1  2  3
         Sex         
System A F    1  1  1
         M    1  1  1
System B F    1  1  1
         M    1  1  1
System C F    1  1  1
         M    1  1  1
```